# Why isn't favicon.ico showing in my ymfony 1.4 project?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, favicon

I've placed the favicon.ico file in the web directory, in the header I have

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Yet I still can't see it. Anyone know why that could be?

Comment: which webserver are you using? Apache, lighttpd, nginx ?

Comment: Do you have a 404 on `h*tp://yoursite.com/favicon.ico`? Did you test on different browser?

Comment: I get an invalid routing rule error and yeah, tried on several browsers...

Comment: @Roy have you checked permissions?

Comment: @Patrick: I have, several times. I feel like I've done everything!

Answer (score -1):

I use `href="/myproject/web/favicon.ico"` that works for me both in development (wamp server,  only FF browser) and production server (Apache, tested with FF, IE and Chrome). Of course you have to remove `/myproject` if you don't use a project folder supposedly in deployment.

Don't forget to clear the browser cache after changing the icon.

Comment: This is nonsense. Did you even try what you suggested?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at the source page of the website infissisrl.it .
I created it with symfony 1.4